# Reading excel file in PHP with PHPExcel library

Tags: php, excel, nginx

When I try to read an uploaded excel file from the upload folder with PHPExcel library, it can cause an error and I can't find the reason. According to the Nginx log, there is "Connection reset by peer" error like below:

```
[error] 111#111: *124 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.17.0.1,
```

Until the line `$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load( $file_name );` everything seems fine but on this line, the file can not be executed and besides this, there isn't any exception in the catch block.

As a result of the problem, Nginx gives `502 Bad Gateway` error in the browser.

```
public function load_excel( $file_name )
    {
        try {
             /**  Identify the type of $inputFileName  **/
            $inputFileType = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify( $file_name );
            /**  Create a new Reader of the type that has been identified  **/
            $objReader = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader( $inputFileType );
            /**  Advise the Reader that we only want to load cell data  **/
            $objReader->setReadDataOnly( true );
            /**  Load $inputFileName to a PHPExcel Object  **/
            $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load( $file_name );
        } catch(\PHPExcel_Reader_Exception $e) {
            error_log($e->getMessage());
            return false;
        }
        return $objPHPExcel;
    }
```

Comment: The reason is about the excel which I edit it in Mac. It can change the format of excel and why the PHP Excel library can not load it.